# DAX formula calculate dates between first transaction and (first transaction + 6 months)

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

**Background**: I have a column in a Customer dimension with a static date(e.g '2013-01-01').
This column is the result of a calculation that gets the first transaction date ever made by that certain customer. This customer dimension is linked to a fact table containing reportdate as a date column linked to a date dimension.

**Goal**: I want to make a calculated measure that, based on a sum of amount measure, calculates the result based on a given period between start_date(First transaction date), end_date (first transaction date + 6 months).

All i get is "cannot be determined in the current context" warnings and cannot get my head around to fix it.

All help is welcome!

Thanks in advance,

/Blixter

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** I replicated the logic from the calculated measure found in the Customer table.

> =CALCULATE([SumAmount];DATESBETWEEN(DimDate[Date];FIRSTDATE(‌​FactTable[Reportdate‌​]);DATEADD(FIRSTDATE‌​(FactTable[Reportdat‌​e]);5;MONTH)))